# Best instruments for "years of schooling"/"education"

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variable

As an answer to question “[Seminal papers that later were proven to contain errors](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/seminal-papers-that-later-were-proven-to-contain-errors/5315#5315)”, @[snoram](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/4193/snoram) mentioned Angrist and Krueger (1991), and there use of quarter of birth as an (exogenous) instrument for education.

@snoram illustrates using (Buckles and Hungerman, 2013) how quarter of birth is in fact correlated with important characteristics of the mother.

In a comment, @snoram write:

> “For the record I think Angrist and Krueger's work is amazing, but
>   today we know better than to use quarter of birth (in the us at least
>   and for this purpose) as an instrument. Science advances.”

**My question** : which variables are know to be better than quarter of birth as instruments for, say, “years of schooling” (or more generally “education”)?

Answer (score 3):

Check out
*Estimating the Return to Schooling: Progress on Some Persistent Econometric
Problems* by David Card (2001) **ECA**

I know distance from school has been used in the past as an IV..although it has been criticized.

Comment: I appreciate the reference +1. If someone wanted to write a self-contained answer that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the instrument is better depends on what outcome you are estimating.

In any case, some instruments that have been used:

- quarter of birth
- distance to schools
- parental education
- spousal education
- number of siblings
- availability of library card at young age
- changes in compulsory schooling laws
- regional differences in availability of pre-schools

Twin studies are also popular.