# Critiques of "The impact of legalized abortion on crime."

Tags: econometrics, identification

The paper "The impact of legalized abortion on crime." by John J. Donohue III  and Steven D. Levitt (of Freakonomics fame) is a rather famous paper from 2001. It is sometimes still cited in university classes to illustrate some econometrics concepts. It is my understanding that there are several issues with the paper, both w.r.t. sampling/identification and coding, but I am not an expert in econometrics. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legalized_abortion_and_crime_effect) they write:

> Critics have argued that Donohue and Levitt's methodologies are flawed and that no statistically significant relationship between abortion and later crime rates can be proven.

I found that so far no Q or A has discussed this here, so here it goes:

**What are the academic critiques of "The impact of legalized abortion on crime"?**

There are probably good papers/chapters/blogposts on this, if you use these in your answer please quote the gist and post the link.

---

I would recommend double posting the answer to here as well: 
[Seminal papers that later were proven to contain errors](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/seminal-papers-that-later-were-proven-to-contain-errors)